# Clear rowcolor at midrule

Tags: tables, color, transparency, colortbl, rowcolor

I'm trying to make my tables look nicer by default.
What I'm looking to do is fill every row between a toprule
and a midrow.

The next row after a toprow can be easily filled by appending
`\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}` to the command.

The issue I have is getting this to work with multi-row table headings.
I've managed to modify `\@xarraycr` so that until a bool is set to false it sets the next row colour to `tableheadcolor`. The issue I have is that this always runs for one row to many.
I managed to almost get around this by overwriting the row color to the stored variable `page`. However that will look funny if the table is ontop of any other content, which is entirely likely to happen at some point.

Despite a fair bit of finagling, I'm unable to get this to work, so I'm turning to StackExchange for help. Unfortunately none of the similar questions I've seen have been able to help.

This is what I've currently got (colours garish for demonstration purposes)

[image: demo image]

## Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ctable}


\colorlet{text}{black}
\colorlet{page}{white}


\newbool{tabularTitleRow}
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{black!5} % Table header colour = 25% gray

\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{%
    \global\boolfalse{tabularTitleRow}
}

\renewcommand{\toprule}{
    \arrayrulecolor{text}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{text}\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}%
    \global\booltrue{tabularTitleRow}%
}

\let\oldmidrule\midrule
\renewcommand{\midrule}{
    \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{
        \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{text}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{page}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
        \arrayrulecolor{text}%
        \rowcolor{page}%
        % \global\rownum=0\relax%
        \global\boolfalse{tabularTitleRow}%
    }{%
        \oldmidrule
    }
}







\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{orange!30!page}

\catcode`@=11 % or \catcode"0040=11 or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@xarraycr

\let\old@xarraycr\@xarraycr

\def\@xarraycr{%
{\texttt{\tiny EOL}}
\old@xarraycr \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}}{}}

\catcode`@=12 % or \catcode"0040=12 or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12




\begin{document}




\pagecolor{blue!10}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    & & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \toprule
    a & b & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \midrule
    4 & 5 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    % \meaning\\ & & \\
    \toprule
    7 & 8 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    & & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \toprule
    a & b & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    d & e & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    4 & 5 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
    \bottomrule
    7 & 8 & \ifbool{tabularTitleRow}{T}{F} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

If it would also be possible to have the heading colour be transparent,
I have been unable to find how to do that, but I'm fairly sure you know more than me.

Also interested in a better approach to accomplish the overall effect.

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to achieve. What's wrong in the images you posted?

Comment: So in the photos the 1,2,F row has a solid fill. I'm trying to avoid that row having a different colour or opacity to the rest of the table (rows 4,5,F etc), this whole question is because I can't find a way around this so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your off-by-one row colouring is that when your modified `\midrule` sets your `tabularTitleRow` boolean flag to false, it is already too late: the preceding `\\` command has already put the `\rowcolor` call that sets the row color for header rows. Moreover, your way of modifying `\@xarraycr` is nasty, because it prevents the `\\[〈dimen〉]` syntax from working inside a `tabular` or `array`. So, it's better not to redefine `\@xarraycr` if possible (as done below).

Based on Ulrike Fischer's idea about [using `\hiderowcolors`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494954/73317), here is a way to get the space above the `\midrule` coloured in the proper colour for the table header (but see below for a more elaborate solution based on this technique):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ctable} % or booktabs

\colorlet{text}{black}
\colorlet{page}{white}
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{orange!30!page}

% Use of \showrowcolors and \hiderowcolors is an idea from Ulrike
% Fischer's answer here: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494954/73317>
\renewcommand{\toprule}{%
    \showrowcolors
    \arrayrulecolor{text}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{text}%
    \rowcolor{tableheadcolor}%
}

\apptocmd\midrule{\hiderowcolors}{}{\FAILED}

\makeatletter

\let\@BTrule@ORI=\@BTrule
\let\my@BTrule=\@BTrule

% Modified version of \@BTrule that doesn't do \vskip\@aboverulesep, for use
% when the corresponding vertical space should be coloured.
\patchcmd{\my@BTrule}{%
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  }{%
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\else
  }{}{\FAILED}

\newcommand*{\myendtablehead}{%
 \\[\aboverulesep] % this colours the additional space with the current row
                   % color
 \noalign{\global\let\@BTrule\my@BTrule}% temporarily modify \@BTrule
 \midrule
 \noalign{\global\let\@BTrule\@BTrule@ORI}% restore it
}

\makeatother

\rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue!10}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    a & b \\
    d & e \myendtablehead
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
    7 & 8 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Here is a solution that allows you to write the `\\` before `\midrule`, as usual, without needing to explicitly call `\myendtablehead`. Note that for `\midrule` to be recognized by the modified `\@arraycr`, it must immediately follow the `\\` command (well, there may be space tokens between them, but nothing else).

Since the `\rowcolors` command respects grouping, we define a `coloredtableheaders` environment inside which alignments are colored according to this scheme. Outside this environment, `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\@arraycr` have their usual meaning. Any `\rowcolors` command used outside the `coloredtableheaders` environment is independent of what we do inside, and should behave as usual.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs} % or ctable

\colorlet{text}{black}
\colorlet{page}{white}
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{orange!30!page}

\makeatletter

% The use of \showrowcolors and \hiderowcolors is an idea from Ulrike
% Fischer's answer here: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494954/73317>
\newcommand*{\my@coloredtoprule}{%
  \showrowcolors
  \arrayrulecolor{text}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
  \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
  \arrayrulecolor{text}%
  \rowcolor{tableheadcolor}%
}

\let\my@coloredmidrule\midrule
\apptocmd\my@coloredmidrule{\hiderowcolors}{}{\FAILED}

\let\@BTrule@ORI=\@BTrule
\let\my@BTrule=\@BTrule

% Modified version of \@BTrule that doesn't do \vskip\@aboverulesep, for use
% when the corresponding vertical space should be coloured.
\patchcmd{\my@BTrule}{%
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  }{%
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\else
  }{}{\FAILED}

\let\@arraycrORI=\@arraycr

% The “master counter” hackery is explained in the TeXbook appendix D (Dirty
% Tricks), pp. 385-386. It is also mentioned in the array.sty implementation
% notes concerning \@arraycr.
\newcommand*{\my@colored@arraycr}{%
  % Increase the master counter. This is needed to prevent TeX from
  % prematurely finishing the alignment entry in case \\ was followed by '&'
  % (when the \futurelet from \@ifnextchar causes TeX to read a '&', this
  % finishes the entry unless the master counter has a different value than it
  % had when the entry was started).
  \relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum 0=`}\fi
  % Each of the two branches takes care of decreasing the master counter.
  \@ifnextchar\midrule
    {\@firstoftwo{\my@endtablehead}}% gobble the following \midrule
    {\my@closebrace@and@arraycrORI}%
}

\newcommand*{\my@endtablehead}{%
  \ifnum 0=`{}\fi % the second brace decreases the master counter
  \@arraycrORI[\aboverulesep]% this colours the additional space with the
                             % current row color
  \noalign{\global\let\@BTrule\my@BTrule}% temporarily modify \@BTrule
  \midrule
  \noalign{\global\let\@BTrule\@BTrule@ORI}% restore it
}

\newcommand*{\my@closebrace@and@arraycrORI}{%
  \ifnum 0=`{}\fi % the second brace decreases the master counter
  \@arraycrORI
}

\newenvironment{coloredtableheaders}{%
  \let\toprule\my@coloredtoprule
  \let\midrule\my@coloredmidrule
  \let\@arraycr\my@colored@arraycr
  \rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \unskip\ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue!10}

No colored header in the following \verb|tabular|:\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
   a \\
   b \\
   c
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{coloredtableheaders}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    a & b \\
    d & e \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
    7 & 8 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{4ex}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{3pt}\normalsize}l>{\hspace{5pt}}*{3}{p{7.9em}}}
    \toprule
    Category & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\normalsize Packages} \\
    \midrule
    General  & etb & xpt & sil \\
             & tts & ttc & frm \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{coloredtableheaders}

\vspace{4ex}
No colored header in the following \verb|tabular|:\quad
\begin{tabular}{lr}
  Foo     & 1\\
  Bar     & 2\\
  And baz & 3
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Using `\cline` in the colored header

As documented in the `colortbl` manual:

> Lines produced by `\cline` are coloured if you use `\arrayrulecolor` but you may not notice as they are covered up by any colour pannels in the following row. This is a ‘feature’ of `\cline`. If using this package you would probably [be] better using the `-` rule type in a `\hhline` argument, rather than `\cline`.

Example using the above code and the `hhline` package:

```latex
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    a & \multicolumn{2}{c}{b} \\
    % \cline{2-3} % problem: covered by the next colored row
    % \hhline provides a viable alternative:
    \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}--}
      & c & d\\ \midrule
    e & f & g \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nice! It's almost perfect except for the requirement that you drop a `\\\\` before using it. If that requirement could be removed, I think it would be a more-or-less perfect solution.

Comment: Please see my edit, it should do what you want.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ooops. Looks like I spoke too soon. I tried that as a drop in replacement,
and suddenly I'm getting "misplaced \cr" errors. See https://pastebin.com/rEJB5eGr for a MWE.

Comment: This problem is fixed now. I've added your problematic example with the last two columns removed to the sample code at the end of my answer, it works fine now (I removed two columns only to avoid an overfull `\hbox` due to the default `\linewidth`, but don't worry, it also works with them).

Comment: It's been a while but I've noticed another niggle. If I have a tabular without a header (rows then \midrule) then the entire tabular is shaded. This is not the desired behaviour. Would it be possible to fix this? — what makes this somewhat annoying is particularly the way it makes matrixes shaded, see https://i.postimg.cc/7LwrB7mW/image.png

Comment: @tecosaur Hi, I don't have time right now but will have a look.

Comment: @tecosaur How do you use the code? It is not very clear to me. The [link you posted](https://i.postimg.cc/7LwrB7mW/image.png) doesn't show any `\toprule`, and if I write a `tabular` such as `\begin{tabular}{lcc}
  Foo & is & foo\\
  Bar & means & what it means\\
  And baz & is & pretty quux.
\end{tabular}` with the code from my answer, there is no coloring inside except for the page background set with `\pagecolor`.

Comment: I've just tried to create a MWE and as you said, just your code doesn't produce this. Sorry for possibly unfairly attributing this to your code. I'll try to either (a) narrow it down or (b) produce a working MWE and then get back to you. Thanks for responding to my original message by the way :)

Comment: Got it! By fiddling around with the 'body' of your original MWE I have got a working demo — https://pastebin.com/ZGyurPfU. For me this produces this issue: https://i.postimg.cc/cLLph9SJ/image.png. It seems this happens for any table before the first table with a midrule.

Comment: Okay, please see my last edit. What you saw comes from the fact that `\rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}` was being set globally. In the latest edit, I defined a new environment called `coloredtableheaders`. Changes to `\rowcolors`, `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\@arraycr` are now confined to this environment. I believe this should fix the problem you reported.

Comment: Thanks @frpugon. I imagine it would be fairly easy to rename `tabular` to `oldtabular` and then have `coloredtableheaders` named `tabular` do that it can serve as a transparent replacement. Alteratively is there a way to achieve the effect that having a `\midrule` before the rule-less table without having to make it a custom-named environment? I ask because I want to use this as a 'transparent' extension to a tabular.

Comment: Did you look closely enough? Inside `coloredtableheaders`, normal `tabular` syntax is used, only the command *definitions* are modified to produce the colored header. You need something to tell when you want colored headers and when you don't. It can't be in `\toprule` because `\toprule` has to occur inside a `tabular` whereas `\rowcolors` must be issued before. And as you noticed, doing `\rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}` at global level colors all tables (except those having `\hiderowcolors`), regardless of whether they have a top or mid rule.

Comment: I do see that. What I was thinking though, is since (as can be seen in my example earlier today) **after** a table with a midrule is produced everything works as intended — might it be possible to produce this effect before the document begins? This way we'd seem to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: To clarify / add a bit more. If I put `\begin{tabular}{l}\hiderowcolors\end{tabular}` at the start of a document, then I don't have this issue and there's no need for the two environments as far as I can tell. I'm hoping it's possible to achieve this effect without having to include this at the start of the 'body' of every document (I use this in a class file).

Comment: It seems to work if you start from the previous revision (i.e., before I added the `coloredtableheaders` environment—for instance, as in the [link you posted](https://pastebin.com/ZGyurPfU)) and add `\AtBeginDocument{\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tabular}{l}\hiderowcolors\end{tabular}}}` to the preamble. However, if the document uses `\rowcolors` for something else than these table headers, you'll have to do again the `\rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}` setup before the next `\toprule`, otherwise the next header won't be in the expected color.

Comment: Hello again frougon! Sorry to keep on bothering you, take it as a sign of how much I've been using (and appreciated) your answer and help so far :D. I've noticed that a `\cline` in the header seems to be filled-over by the shading. If you could help with this latest issue of mine that would be fantastic!

Comment: Gaaa, this looks like a never ending story... TeX alignments are already difficult, `booktabs` hacks on `tabular` and `array`, then add color, stuff the `booktabs` author didn't anticipate or want to deal with... I fear you'll always find something that can break if you try the myriad packages that hack around tabular material. Please post a minimal example, but don't hold your breath—I don't even know how `\cline` works internally.

Comment: Sorry about the hassle. I've been using this as a drop-in replacement for my tabulars. If it is possible to make this work that would be fantastic! `\cline` seems to be defined in `latex.ltx`, specifically on line 5487. For a MWE just use something like `\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule a & \multicolumn{2}{c}{b} \\ \cline{2-3} & c & d \\ \midrule e & f & g \\\bottomrule\end{tabular}` in your earlier answer. I hope it's possible to do something with that, I'd really appreciate it! If not, no worries.

Comment: This is a known problem with `\cline` (see section *Less fun with `\cline`* in the `colortbl` documentation), it has nothing to do with my code. In the table from your previous comment, the problem can be avoided by using `\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}--}` instead of  `\cline{2-3}` (with `\usepackage{hhline}`, of course).

Comment: I see. Thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 4):

You can clear colors with \hiderowcolors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\colorlet{text}{black}
\colorlet{page}{white}


\renewcommand{\toprule}{%
    \showrowcolors\arrayrulecolor{text}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{text}}%

\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{orange!30!page}
\apptocmd\midrule{\hiderowcolors}{}{\fail}
\rowcolors{1}{tableheadcolor}{tableheadcolor}
\begin{document}

\pagecolor{blue!10}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    & & \\
    \toprule
    a & b & \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & \\
    \midrule
    4 & 5 & \\
    \midrule
    7 & 8 & 
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    a & b & \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & \\
    \midrule
    4 & 5 & \\
    % \meaning\\ & & \\
    \midrule
    7 & 8 & 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.25).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\colorlet{text}{black}
\colorlet{page}{white}
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{orange!30!page}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldmidrule}{\midrule}
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\midrule}{}{\oldmidrule\rowlistcolors{}}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue!10}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[color-inside]
    \toprule
    \rowlistcolors{tableheadcolor}
    a & b \\
    d & e \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 \\
    4 & 5 \\
    7 & 8 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

However, as usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]